# Scraping an URL that I scraped while parsing

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

In the spider I have, I get my startURLs from an excel file.

What I'm trying to scrape here are different variant of shoes I get from the amazon site. I first scrape the generic shoe, for example, Nike Woman Shoe and, once I'm in that page, I get every variant (shoe size and color).

Something like this page

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01F2M4EUM?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=97H1JYZTD1M7YN7GRJW2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F2M4EUM)

From this page I get every variant with every product code associated with the variant but, in this URL I cant scrape the price and pictures, because this data only appears when I select a certain shoe size and color.

What I did in my attempt to scrape the prices was formatting an amazon link, which makes prices appear (Trying urls out from amazon I found that this worked)

For example, from this url:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01F2M4EUM?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=97H1JYZTD1M7YN7GRJW2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F2M4EUM)

I manually select a size and color and I get:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0187Q0XWS?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=97H1JYZTD1M7YN7GRJW2&th=1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0187Q0XWS)

This Url I can format (inserting a different product code) and price appears.

Sorry for the long explanation, just trying to be as descriptive as possible.

My spider looks like this:

```
def parse(self,response):
    variationValues = re.findall(r'variationValues\" : ({.*?})', ' '.join(script))[0]
    asinToDimensionIndexMap = re.findall(r'asinToDimensionIndexMap\" : ({.*})', ' '.join(script))[0]
    variationValuesDict = json.loads(variationValues)
    asinToDimensionIndexMapDict = json.loads(asinToDimensionIndexMap)
    productKeys = asinToDimensionIndexMapDict.keys()

    for key in productKeys:

        numeroTalle = asinToDimensionIndexMapDict[key][0]
        numeroColor = asinToDimensionIndexMapDict[key][1]

        clothesAmz_item['codigoGenericoProducto'] = codigoUUID
        clothesAmz_item['codigoEspecificoProducto'] = key
        clothesAmz_item['nombreProducto'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[contains(@id, "productTitle")]/text())').extract()
        clothesAmz_item['urlProducto'] = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/{}?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=48QP07X56PTH002QVCPM&th=1&psc=1'.format(key)                    
        clothesAmz_item['talleProducto'] = variationValuesDict["size_name"][numeroTalle]
        clothesAmz_item['modeloProducto'] = variationValuesDict["color_name"][numeroColor]

        yield clothesAmz_item
```

So, what I want to do is, instead of yielding the item, parse the url I got (urlProducto) so I can get the price of the variant

I tried doing something like this

```
    yield Request(urlProducto, callback = self.parse_specific)

def parse_specific(self,response):

    clothesAmz_item['precioProducto'] = response.xpath('//span[contains(@id, "priceblock")]/text()'.strip()).extract()

    yield clothesAmz_item
```

By doing this, nothing really happens, in the console I can see my spider going through the startURLs that I got from the file but no data is being collected.

I'd like to add that, if I run the first spider I wrote on this question, the program works just fine, but I cant get the individual prices

Any idea whats going on?

items.py

```
class ClothesItem(scrapy.Item):

#DatosProducto
codigoGenericoProducto = scrapy.Field()
codigoEspecificoProducto = scrapy.Field()
categoriaProducto = scrapy.Field()
nombreProducto = scrapy.Field()
precioProducto = scrapy.Field()
urlProducto = scrapy.Field()
talleProducto = scrapy.Field()
modeloProducto = scrapy.Field()

#Imagenes
img0Producto = scrapy.Field()
img1Producto = scrapy.Field()
img2Producto = scrapy.Field()
img3Producto = scrapy.Field()
img4Producto = scrapy.Field()
img5Producto = scrapy.Field()

pass
```

EDIT: Added items.py and more spider code. I get no errors when running the program. Program works fine until I add the Request.(url, callback = parse_specific) part.

Comment: Could you provide your complete code? (in the last snippet `clothesAmz_item` is not even defined) Do you get any error? Have you tried [debugging](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html)? Are you aware of [Request.meta](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta)?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

`response.xpath('//span[contains(@id, "priceblock")]/text()'.strip()).extract()` - THIS IS WRONG. MUST BE `response.xpath('//span[contains(@id, "priceblock")]/text()').extract()` Then strip in clothesAmz_item['precioProducto'] array

Comment: Thats not really the issue I'm having here, in other products I scraped price comes out fine with the xpath i used. The problem I'm encountering, or what I'm trying to achieve is to scrape an URL that I got from scraping another page in the same process. The idea is to use like 2 parsers but make this parsers affect the same scrapy Item