# Scraping an URL i got from scraping a page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm running into some issues while trying to scrape a page. I asked this previously but probably my question was quite confusing.

Link to previous question
[Scraping an URL that I scraped while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412543/scraping-an-url-that-i-scraped-while-parsing?noredirect=1#comment95683123_54412543)

Basically what I'm trying to do is parsing an URL I got from another page, while keeping the same Item.

I get some data from a page, which is assigned to certain Item fields. What I want to do is to add more data to that item but from a URL I get while parsing the previous one.

Something like this:

```
def parse (self,response):

    someItem['name'] = 'something'
    someItem['size'] = 'something'

    #This URL i get from scraping the initial page
    followingURL = someURL

    yield Request(followingURL, callback = self.parseNext)

def parseNext (self,response):

    someItem['color'] = 'somethingIGetFromTheNewPage'

    yield someItem
```

I tried using something along the lines of

```
yield Request(followingURL, callback = self.parseNext, meta={'someItem' : someItem})
```

But it did not work.

How can scrape a new URL while 'saving' the item information i got from the 'parse' method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the right way. It is the most convenient way to pass data from one function to another.
How did you get data in your `parseNext` function? It should be like this:

```
def parseNext(self, response):
    someItem = response.meta['someItem']
    someItem['color'] = 'somethingIGetFromTheNewPage'
    yield someItem
```

Comment: It worked!, i forgot to add someItem = response.meta['someItem'] at the start of the parseNext method.

Thanks for the help!